# IL switch instruction

Tags: c#, cil

I am researching IL code which generated from this C# code (**RELEASE**):

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
switch(a)
{
    case 1:  Console.WriteLine(); break;
    case 2:  Console.WriteLine(); break;
    case 3:  Console.WriteLine(); break;
    case 15: Console.WriteLine(); break;
    default: Console.WriteLine(); break;
}
```

IL:

```
//Why not "switch(IL_0026, IL_002c, IL_0032, IL_0038)"?
IL_000e: switch (IL_0026, IL_002c, IL_0032)

IL_001f: ldloc.0
IL_0020: ldc.i4.s 15
IL_0022: beq.s IL_0038

IL_0024: br.s IL_003e

IL_0026: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_002b: ret

IL_002c: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_0031: ret

IL_0032: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_0037: ret

IL_0038: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_003d: ret

IL_003e: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_0043: ret
```

Why "switch" in IL works with sequence (1,2,3... n+1) and do not add other values (for exapmle: for 15 generated 3 instruction (001f, 0020, 0022))

Comment: You'd rather it emitted a jump table 12 entries longer, with 11 of those jumping to the default case, rather than those 3 instructions after the 3 contiguous cases?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever aaah that's the thing. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> //Why not "switch(IL_0026, IL_002c, IL_0032, IL_0038)"?
> ```

Because that 4th label would be jumped to if the value of `a` was 4, not 15. The jump targets in a `switch` correspond to *successive values* of the tested value.

In order to use `switch` and not have the additional special case for `15`, it would need to be:

```
switch(IL_0026, IL_002c, IL_0032, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_0038)
```

(I hope I've counted right)

Which would be a much larger jump table.

---

I'd always recommend checking out the documentation for `Reflection.Emit` for the instruction you're looking at, e.g. [`OpCodes.Switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.switch?view=net-6.0), to make sure you understand what the instruction does.

> The switch instruction pops a value off the stack and compares it, as an unsigned integer, to `N`. If value is less than `N`, execution is transferred to the target indexed by value, where targets are numbered from 0 (for example, a value of 0 takes the first target, a value of 1 takes the second target, and so on).